# how do I change my div style to a value that is from my database?

Tags: javascript, html, database, styles, progress-bar

I am doing a progress bar based on the value that I wish to capture from my database. Whereas from here, it is determined by the div style = width: "?%" to determine the length of the progress bar. How do I get this value from my database to be input in it?

```
<div class="container">
 <h2>Basic Progress Bar</h2>
  <div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria- 
   valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
   70% Complete
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you read the Values from your Database.
If you use PHP, you can simply write the PHP-variable directly in your HTML-code.

For Example:

```
<?php echo $percent; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assign an id to your div so that it can be easily identified using JavaScript.

```
<div id="yourDiv" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria- 
valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%"> <!-- Default to width: 70% -->
```

In the JavaScript part where you got the data from your database, call this

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.width = divPercentFromDatabase; // Example*   = "70%"
```

After the line is executed, your div's width will be changed according to the variable specify there.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the width of your  element by changing the style.width property with JavaScript.

```
funcion changeWidth(newWidth) {
var progressBar = document.propertySelector('progress-bar');
progressBar.style.width = newWidth + '%';
};
```